# Preview rounded image in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, uiimageview

can anyone tell me how can I create an image preview inside a customized cell with the aspect of the ones loaded in the mms'.

I've been trying to do it by changing values in IB and I haven't been able to.

Thanks a lot!

[image]
<sub>(source: [iphonehelp.in](http://iphonehelp.in/content/uploads/2009/03/30-mms.jpg))</sub>

---

Thanks for the three answers.

Doing

```
cell3.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell3.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 16;
cell3.imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
cell3.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
```

I was able to do part of what I want. However, I still can't put that "glow" look on the image. Does anybody now which property should I control?

Thanks a lot (and thanks again).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sure. Add the QuartzCore framework to your project, then:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
// ...
cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
```

Note that the `cornerRadius` property is only available in OS 3.0 and later; if you're supporting an older version (which you probably don't have to be), you'll need to do some Core Graphics work.

Answer (score 0):

will creating an image in an image editor and then setting it as the cell's background not work?

This might be useful for you
 http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Answer (score 0):

If your image is in an image view and you're targeting OS 3.0+, you can set `imageView.layer.cornerRadius`.