# How to draw a rounded rectangle in Core Graphics / Quartz 2D?

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics

I need to draw an outline for a rounded rectangle. I know I can make lines and arcs, but maybe there is also a function for rounded rects?

Comment: example code http://stackoverflow.com/a/19142851/294884

Answer (score 131):

Instead of making your own path out of lines and arcs, you can use

```
[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cornerRadius:]
```

or

```
[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:]
```

(the second one lets you specify which corners are rounded)

Available in iOS 3.2 or later.

Comment: Don't forget to properly inset the rectangle when stroking even if your line width is only one pixel: `CGRectInset(rect, lineWidth, lineWidth)`

Comment: Just for completeness, it's also helpful to show what you do with that:
```objc

[[UIColor lightGrayColor] setFill];  // set rounded rect's bg color             

UIBezierPath *roundedRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: _yourDrawingFrame cornerRadius: 4];

[roundedRect fillWithBlendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0f];
```

Comment: Actually when stroking I believe the rect should only be inset by half the lineWidth i.e. `CGRectInset(rect, lineWidth/2.0, lineWidth/2.0)`. This is because "the drawn line is centered on the path with its sides parallel to the path segment" (cf. `-[UIBezierPath strokeWithBlendMode:alpha:]`)

Comment: You can also use `CGPathAddRoundedRect` if you're more into CoreGraphics approaches and supporting iOS 7.0 and on only.

Answer (score 62):

There is no prepackaged way to this, you must combine arcs in order to do this, apples quartzdemo project shows the code to do this, here is a reference [Quartz Demo](http://web.archive.org/web/20100602144213/http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/QuartzDemo/Listings/Quartz_QuartzCurves_m.html) and here is the code they provide

```
  // As a bonus, we'll combine arcs to create a round rectangle! 
 
// Drawing with a white stroke color 
 CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); 
  
// If you were making this as a routine, you would probably accept a rectangle 
// that defines its bounds, and a radius reflecting the "rounded-ness" of the rectangle. 
CGRect rrect = CGRectMake(210.0, 90.0, 60.0, 60.0); 
CGFloat radius = 10.0; 
// NOTE: At this point you may want to verify that your radius is no more than half 
// the width and height of your rectangle, as this technique degenerates for those cases. 
 
// In order to draw a rounded rectangle, we will take advantage of the fact that 
// CGContextAddArcToPoint will draw straight lines past the start and end of the arc 
// in order to create the path from the current position and the destination position. 
 
// In order to create the 4 arcs correctly, we need to know the min, mid and max positions 
// on the x and y lengths of the given rectangle. 
CGFloat minx = CGRectGetMinX(rrect), midx = CGRectGetMidX(rrect), maxx = CGRectGetMaxX(rrect); 
CGFloat miny = CGRectGetMinY(rrect), midy = CGRectGetMidY(rrect), maxy = CGRectGetMaxY(rrect); 
 
// Next, we will go around the rectangle in the order given by the figure below. 
//       minx    midx    maxx 
// miny    2       3       4 
// midy   1 9              5 
// maxy    8       7       6 
// Which gives us a coincident start and end point, which is incidental to this technique, but still doesn't 
// form a closed path, so we still need to close the path to connect the ends correctly. 
// Thus we start by moving to point 1, then adding arcs through each pair of points that follows. 
// You could use a similar tecgnique to create any shape with rounded corners. 
 
// Start at 1 
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, minx, midy); 
// Add an arc through 2 to 3 
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, minx, miny, midx, miny, radius); 
// Add an arc through 4 to 5 
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, maxx, miny, maxx, midy, radius); 
// Add an arc through 6 to 7 
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, maxx, maxy, midx, maxy, radius); 
// Add an arc through 8 to 9 
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, minx, maxy, minx, midy, radius); 
// Close the path 
CGContextClosePath(context); 
// Fill & stroke the path 
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

Comment: If anyone is wondering how `CGContextAddArcToPoint()` works, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18992153/1338292) is a pretty good explanation.

Answer (score 48):

```
 UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:bubbleBounds cornerRadius:15.0];
 CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor grayColor].CGColor);
 [bezierPath stroke];
```

Answer (score 23):

Here is a function I wrote that rounds the input rect using a corner radius.

```
CGMutablePathRef createRoundedCornerPath(CGRect rect, CGFloat cornerRadius) {

    // create a mutable path
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

    // get the 4 corners of the rect
    CGPoint topLeft = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y);
    CGPoint topRight = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x + rect.size.width, rect.origin.y);
    CGPoint bottomRight = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x + rect.size.width, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height);
    CGPoint bottomLeft = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height);

    // move to top left
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, topLeft.x + cornerRadius, topLeft.y);

    // add top line
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, topRight.x - cornerRadius, topRight.y);

    // add top right curve
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, topRight.x, topRight.y, topRight.x, topRight.y + cornerRadius);

    // add right line
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y - cornerRadius);

    // add bottom right curve
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y, bottomRight.x - cornerRadius, bottomRight.y);

    // add bottom line
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, bottomLeft.x + cornerRadius, bottomLeft.y);

    // add bottom left curve
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, bottomLeft.x, bottomLeft.y, bottomLeft.x, bottomLeft.y - cornerRadius);

    // add left line
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, topLeft.x, topLeft.y + cornerRadius);

    // add top left curve
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, topLeft.x, topLeft.y, topLeft.x + cornerRadius, topLeft.y);

    // return the path
    return path;
}
```

How to use the function, assuming you subclass UIView and override drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    // constants
    const CGFloat outlineStrokeWidth = 20.0f;
    const CGFloat outlineCornerRadius = 15.0f;

    const CGColorRef whiteColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    const CGColorRef redColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];

    // get the context
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // set the background color to white
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, whiteColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    // inset the rect because half of the stroke applied to this path will be on the outside
    CGRect insetRect = CGRectInset(rect, outlineStrokeWidth/2.0f, outlineStrokeWidth/2.0f);

    // get our rounded rect as a path
    CGMutablePathRef path = createRoundedCornerPath(insetRect, outlineCornerRadius);

    // add the path to the context
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);

    // set the stroke params
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, redColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, outlineStrokeWidth);

    // draw the path
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);

    // release the path
    CGPathRelease(path);
}
```

Example output:

[image]

Comment: Go ahead and use the built-in functions. I made this for learning purposes only.

Comment: This doesn't work :     CGMutablePathRef path = createRoundedCornerPath(insetRect, outlineCornerRadius);

Comment: Make sure you've copied the implementation for the createRoundedCornerPath() function included in my response. It also has to be put above the drawRect: method since it's a C function.

Comment: Have a look at BezierPath. Makes it much easier to draw thinks like this

Answer (score 11):

If you want To have rounded corners on any UIView (or subclass) the easy way is to set the cornerRadius property on the view's layer. See [Preview rounded image in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448725/preview-rounded-image-in-iphone/2448903#2448903)

Comment: This is by far the easiest. view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f.
Make sure you import the Quartz framework.

Comment: Should absolutely be the accepted answer. Note that this only works if you set `layer.masksToBounds` to true

Answer (score 10):

[`CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect) will do what you want.

```
CGPathRef CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(
   CGRect rect,
   CGFloat cornerWidth,
   CGFloat cornerHeight,
   const CGAffineTransform *transform
);
```

Available starting in iOS 7.0

Comment: I'm pretty sure this DOES NOT GIVE YOU the new iOS7 rounded corners.  Use bezierPathWithRoundedRect for the new iOS7 rounded corners...

Comment: @JoeBlow Not sure what you mean by that, this function was added only in iOS7 and gives you rounded corners; is there another rounded corners?

Answer (score 9):

**Swift:**

```
    let rect: CGRect = ...
    
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 5.0)
    context.addPath(path.cgPath)
    context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.clear.cgColor)
    context.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe... three? years late, but these days I'm using this without issues.

```
@import CoreGraphics;

@interface YourViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *theButton;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.theButton.layer.cornerRadius  = 5.0f;
    self.theButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    // Another useful ones
    // Scaling the view (width, height)
    self.theButton.transform = CGAfflineTransformMakeScale(1.50f, 1.50f);

    // Setting an alpha value (transparency) - nice with Activity Indicator subviews
    self.theButton.alpha     = 0.8f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.2

```
    let lineWidth: CGFloat = 5.0
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect.insetBy(dx: lineWidth/2.0, dy: lineWidth/2.0), cornerRadius: 10。0)
    path.lineWidth = lineWidth
    UIColor.green.setStroke()
    path.stroke()
```