# Draw a Rounded Rectangle programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to draw a rounded rectangle in Core Graphics / Quartz 2D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835448/how-to-draw-a-rounded-rectangle-in-core-graphics-quartz-2d)

I want to draw a rounded rectangle programmatically for my overlaying UIView,

how would I approach this?

Answer (score 3):

NSBezierPath has a special `+bezierPathWithRoundedRect:xRadius:yRadius:`, check the documentation.

```
NSBezierPath *path =
  [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:NSMakeRect(...)
                                  xRadius:3.0f
                                  yRadius:3.0f];
[path fill];
```