# iOS 7 round framed button

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

the iOS App Store has a blue round framed button for buying/downloading apps.

In my App you can download additional content and I want to have a similar button, just because it looks familiar to the user.

If you don't know, what I mean: these buttons, like "$3.99"

[image]

How is this possible?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

You can manipulate the CALayer of your button to do this pretty easily.

```
// assuming you have a UIButton or more generally a UIView called buyButton

buyButton.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
buyButton.layer.borderWidth = 1;
buyButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
// (note - may prefer to use the tintColor of the control)
```

you can tweak each of those to get the color and border effect you want.

You will also have to add an import in any file you want to use CALayers

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: It should be noted that this is the preferred way of creating round rect/bordered views, even long before iOS 7.

Comment: I made a library which looks the same as well as the animation when pressed. Hope this helps: https://github.com/yhpark/YHRoundBorderedButton

Comment: Hello I am in problem well I only need to round the Top RIght and Botton Right corner of my button so how can i do it ? please suggest Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 90):

If you are a big fan of using storyboards for your UI design with iOS.. you can set the corner radius (and whichever other parameters as mentioned in dima's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19143035/766570) -- although unfortunately not the color, since it's a CGColor and Apple presently does not have that option in the popup) in the `identity inspector`->`user defined runtime attributes` in storyboard as shown here:

[image]

**bonus:**
you use runtime attributes for `UIButton` placeholder text color (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22017127/766570)) and to change fonts of `UILabel`, `UITextField` and `UIButton` as well (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15155081/766570))

Comment: Ahh!  Note that **YOU CAN NOT SET THE COLOR** of borderColor, in interface builder. There is only a Type for "Color". There is **not a type for CGColor** - so unfortunately you cannot do it like this!  (If you want "black" as the CGColor, you can do it!)

Comment: It works for corner radius but not for borderWidth and borderColor

Answer (score 17):

For standard iOS control elements like `UIButton`, `UILabel`,
 you should use the `UIView` `tintColor` property:

```
buyButton.layer.borderColor = buyButton.tintColor.CGColor;
```

Answer (score 8):

For simple border like you described, use the answer from Dima using CALAyer.

If you want more, e.g a rounded rectangle with gradient then use this approach as base:

Create a custom View which draws a rounded rectangle and place it over the button.
Use the search function here to search for draw rounded rectangle.
The drawing works by drawing 4 arcs with defined radius (corners) and 4 straight lines.

---

FTR, here's how you make a UIView with the correct iOS7 rounded corners, per Alex and Brian.

I'm pretty sure that CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect **does not** give you the "new" rounded corners. You have to use bezierPathWithRoundedRect for the "new" corners.

```
#import "UIViewWithIOS7RoundedCorners.h"
@implementation UIViewWithIOS7RoundedCorners
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
    // for a filled shape...

    UIBezierPath* path =
        [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds cornerRadius:4];
    [[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
    [path fill];

    // for just a border...

    int thickness=2;
    UIBezierPath* path =
        [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:
            CGRectInset(self.bounds, thickness/2, thickness/2)
            cornerRadius: 4];
    path.lineWidth = thickness;
    [[UIColor blueColor] setStroke];
    [path stroke];
    }

@end
// ps don't forget to set .backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor]
// perhaps in initWithCoder/initWithFrame
```

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps someone

Comment: This is really not necessary. You can easily add a border/frame using the UIButton's underlying CALayer, see my answer for instructions.

Comment: ah, I remeber, i used the self drawaing for using a gradient.

Comment: Updated, to limit this answer for advanced drawings

Comment: There are a few small advantages to this solution. `+[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cornerRadius:]` uses the new corner radius style.  Also, you could generate a single image to use for all buttons, improving GPU rendering performance.

Comment: my solution seems to be  a bit outdated, now you have UIBezierPath which solves that for you. (But i leanerd much looking on the src of manually drawing the 4 arcs and lines)

Comment: The **new corner radius style** is not a small advantage, it is critical. If it's a fact that this is the only way to get that, then it's the only way to do it.  Great stuff thanks Alex.

Comment: For the record, I don't know if buttons "should" have the new rounded math, or "should" have the ordinary old square rounded math. Of course at small radius, the difference on a few pixel densities is a very small difference. (You can definitely, just barely, see the difference on an iPad Air.) Anyway, I don't know whether buttons **should** have the new rounding, but I'm pretty sure the only way you **can in fact** do the new rounding is exactly as Alex/Brian say here. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented the AppStore style button here for your reference: [ASButton.m](https://github.com/jianpx/ASButton/blob/master/ASButtonExample/ASButtonExample/Sources/UIButton%2BAppStore.m)

and the project is [here](https://github.com/jianpx/ASButton)

Hope to help :]

Answer (score 2):

To extend @abbood 's excellent answer, it is actually possible to set the border color and background color of a view's layer from IB, but it requires a little prep work to do so.

I've created a custom category on NSView, CALayer+setUIColor.h.

The that sets border colors only has one method, setBorderUIColor. It takes a UIColor as an input, fetches the UIColor's underlying NSColor, and applies that color to the view's layer.

Then, in IB, you just add a user defined runtime attribute like this:

KeyPath
  layer.borderUIColor
Type
  color
Value
  The desired color.

At runtime the system invokes your method, passing in the UIColor that's defined in IB. The category gets the CGColor from the UIColor and applies it to the layer.

You can see this in a working project in a github project of mine called

[RandomBlobs](https://github.com/DuncanMC/RandomBlobs)

I've also done the same thing for setting a layer's background color property, but not in the above project.

Answer (score 0):

And for the swift version of Duncan C's extension of abbood's answer:

```
extension CALayer {
    var borderUIColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            if let borderColor = borderColor {
                return UIColor(CGColor: borderColor)
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            borderColor = newValue?.CGColor ?? nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Swift 5.1 / iOS 13, you can create a subclass of `UIButton` in order to have a custom button that will look like the blue rounded border button in iOS AppStore app.

The following code shows how to manage properly the tint color (when the button appears behind the dimmed view of a `UIAlertController`), the title's color, the highlighted background color, the border's style, the border's color and the content insets.

*CustomButton.swift:*

```swift
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setProperties()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setProperties()
    }

    func setProperties() {
        // Set the layer's properties
        layer.borderColor = tintColor?.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.cornerRadius = 4

        // Set colors for title's states
        setTitleColor(tintColor, for: .normal)
        setTitleColor(.white, for: .highlighted)

        // Add some margins between the title (content) and the border
        contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 10, bottom: 5, right: 10)
    }

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            // Toggle the background color according to button's highlighted state
            backgroundColor = super.isHighlighted ? tintColor : nil
        }
    }

    override func tintColorDidChange() {
        super.tintColorDidChange()

        // When the tint color is changed by the system (e.g. when the button appears below the dimmed view of a UIAlertController), we have to manually update border color and title's text color
        layer.borderColor = tintColor?.cgColor
        setTitleColor(tintColor, for: .normal)
    }

}
```

*ViewController.swift:*

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground

        let button = CustomButton()
        button.setTitle("Normal", for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("Highlighted", for: .highlighted)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(presentAlert(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)

        // auto layout
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
    }

    /// Present alert when button is tapped
    @objc func presentAlert(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
        alertController.addAction(alertAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

The images below show how the custom button will appear in normal state, when the system `tinColor` is changed (behind the dimmed view of a `UIAlertController`) and in `highlighted` state.

[image]