# Golden ratio corner rounded frame rectangle button

Tags: ios, ios7, uibutton, icons

How can we make a rounded rectangle frame programatically, as solved with

```
buyButton.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
buyButton.layer.borderWidth = 1;
buyButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
```

in [iOS 7 round framed button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142759/ios-7-round-framed-button)

but resulting in a golden ratio corner such as the one introduced in the iOS 7 icon shape; [image: new icon shape in iOS 7]
[image: iOS 6 and 7 icon difference]?

Comment: Increase the corner radius?

Comment: How did you know it follows golden ratio?

Comment: It does in using a curvature radius related to the whole's dimensions in a certain ratio, look; http://www.razorianfly.com/wp-content/uploads/IOS7-Icon-Grid-System.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the same shape, just measure the image, eg with Photoshop and set the border radius proportional to the button's width. I did the measurement for you:

```
buyButton.layer.borderRadius = 0.315 * buyButton.frame.size.width;
```

I don't think it follows golden ratio thought. If it does, the ratio should be  `(1 - (sqrt(5) - 1)/2)`, which is `0.381...`, which results in too rounded corners.

Comment: Very smart and simple, thank you! Will check on the original but basically, this is the formula for use with a desired ratio

Comment: I see, it's really golden ratio.

Answer (score 1):

There's more to the golden ratio in this template. It appears in the relative sizes of the circles in relation to each other and the width of the template. See http://www.phimatrix.com/product-design-golden-ratio/ for details.