# Bordered iOS 8 Buttons Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I want a flat looking white bordered around my `UIButton`. I would like it in Storyboard or programmatically. My code isn't working.

***Code:***

```
UIButton.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
UIButton.layer.borderWidth = 1;
UIButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "isn't working"? Is it because you're trying to set properties on the UIButton class instead of an instance of that class?

Comment: UiButton.type doesn't have a member named layer is the error

Comment: Right, the UIButton type doesn't have the properties you're trying to access. You need an instance of the class.

Comment: But [in this webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142759/ios-7-round-framed-button) the class has been used

Comment: Also I imported QuartzCore

Comment: It's true that those are UIButton's but they are instances of that class, not the class itself. You need to understand that there is a difference between a class and an instance. Understanding that will clarify the problem with your code.

Answer (score 16):

You should create referencing outlet for your button from storyboard to your VC named for example myButton than set its properties

```
myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
myButton.layer.borderWidth = 1;
myButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to do this with code either. You can create a stretchable image and set it to the background image of the button in the attributes inspector.

[image]

Comment: link is unavailable

Comment: Thanks, the link was removed

Answer (score 1):

as 0x7fffffff said. UIButton is the class it can be instatiated bu invoking its constructor like this

```
let instanceOfUIButton = UIButton()
```

then you can set the desired attributes:

```
instanceOfUIButton.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 8.2 (Swift 3) you can use "Identity Inspector Tab". Search for "Users Defined Runtime Attributes", after selecting your UIButton. There you can define these attributes:

1. Key Path: layer.cornerRadius; 2-Type: Number, 3-Value: 2
2. Key Path: layer.borderWidth; 2-Type: Number, 3-Value: 1
3. Key Path: layer.borderColor; 2-Type: Color, 3-Value: "select white or another one"

Answer (score 0):

Another option instead of creating a reference to each button would be to create a subclass of the type UIButton. You could then set the properties in the subclass. Next you could change the class of all the buttons in the storyboard that need to have the same properties.

```
class MyButton: UIButton {

 override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.White
        layer.cornerRadius = 2
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the top

```
myButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
```