# How to set corner radius within drawRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, drawrect, cornerradius

The code below in my drawRect method draws a rectangle on my view controller. I'd like to set a corner radius to this. What am I missing?

```
CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(20, 22, 280, 460);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255, 255, 255, 1.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);
```

Comment: not a duplicate - your suggestion draws a corner outline and does not apply to my existing object

Comment: the link is fine. you can stroke the rounded rectangle, you can fill it, or you can do both.

Answer (score 6):

Try following, please:

```
CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(20, 22, 280, 460);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255, 255, 255, 1.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
//CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);

UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: rectangle cornerRadius:15.0];

[bezierPath fill];
```

Comment: I still think your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835448/how-to-draw-a-rounded-rectangle-in-core-graphics-quartz-2d

Comment: Swift:

fillColor.setFill();  
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius);
    path.fill();